# Exeeuted in model using python on triton inference server getting issue json parser

Tags: python, json, model

```
python3 /home/ubuntu/Deepthi/triton-inference-server-master/src/clients/python/examples/image_client.py -m /home/ubuntu/Deepthi/triton-inference-server-master/docs/model_repository/resnet50_netdef/1 -s INCEPTION /home/ubuntu/Deepthi/triton-inference-server-master/qa/images/mug.jpg
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ubuntu/Deepthi/triton-inference-server-master/src/clients/python/examples/image_client.py", line 403, in <module>
    model_name=FLAGS.model_name, model_version=FLAGS.model_version)
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tritonhttpclient/__init__.py", line 471, in get_model_metadata
    _raise_if_error(response)
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tritonhttpclient/__init__.py", line 57, in _raise_if_error
    error = _get_error(response)
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tritonhttpclient/__init__.py", line 46, in _get_error
    error_response = json.loads(response.read())
rapidjson.JSONDecodeError: Parse error at offset 0: The document is empty.
```

I am not getting why I am getting this error, everything is ready .

Comment: This question require more input information, could you please share versions you're using and also content of your files; Might be related to this issue: https://github.com/triton-inference-server/server/issues/2495